# add time interval to user input date/time from UIdatepicker in Swift

Tags: swift, calendar, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker, dateformatter

I have tried several different routes (including sample code on Apple Developer site's DateFormatter) to take a user-input date/time from UIDatePicker and add 8 hours to it, then reproduce the new date/time in results displayed via label to user.  Have googled/youtubed/sifted through apple dev site for three days.  Tried Calendar, tried NSDateFormatter which brought me to DateFormatter (updated) and no dice.  New to this, any advice would be much appreciated!

Here is what I have now, printing to a test label.   It is printing tomorrow's date with the time set in picker, not adding hours though and skipping to tomorrow's date randomly in simulator when I change the picker time.  What am I doing incorrectly here?  I tried creating a new calendar & date inside startPicker and calling that after let eightHrPoint =, but I cannot figure out how to make this work.

```
    // Start Time
@IBOutlet weak var startPicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBAction func startValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {

}


//Testing Label for 8 hour interval
@IBOutlet weak var eightHrLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func submitPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let eightHrPoint = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: startPicker.date)!
    print("\(eightHrPoint)")
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and what issues you are facing

Comment: Calendar has a method called `date(byAdding component: Calendar.Component, value: Int, to date: Date, wrappingComponents: Bool = default) -> Date?` which you can use as follow  `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: datePicker.date)!`

Comment: Leo, thank you for your help!  I updated above, still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: your date it is correct. When printing a date it shows UTC time.

Comment: finally figured it all out and got it to do what I need.  Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome